# Cyberduck CLI: uploading public file to DigitalOcean Space/Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I am trying to upload a file to DigitalOcean space with Cyberduck CLI https://duck.sh/ from Windows 10 box like that:

```
duck --upload digitalocean-ams3://myspace/dir/ test.txt
```

This works, but the uploaded file is "private", while I need to make it public.

I tried to manually set permission as per command line reference, but this does not seem to make any difference.

```
duck --chmod 604 --upload digitalocean-ams3://myspace/dir/ test.txt
```

With GUI version of Cyberduck all seems to work fine. Forcing permission as per guidelines here makes uploaded files public https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/spaces/resources/cyberduck/.

Is there a way to force ACL as "read by everyone" from CLI version of Cyberduck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ACL control with S3 uploads is not supported at this moment in Cyberduck CLI.

See https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/9425